# Batch to open and close a program

Tags: batch-file, command-line, scheduled-tasks

We have a program deployed to citrix users that occasionally requires that someone open it so it can display a "This program will be updated once you close this message" dialogue box. I'm trying to get something going in task scheduler to automate that, so I came up with a batch file that will open the program, then close it. The batch file works great when ran manually, but seems to run perpetually in scheduler without ever actually doing what it is supposed to do. Here's what I wrote for the batch:

```
start C:\filepath
timeout 30
cls
taskkill /IM task that hangs up when the batch closes it /T /F
```

This is running on Server 2012 R2

Comment: Check the following: //// 1) batch is running in that user's interactive session and not under SYSTEM or LOCAL account (check task schedule settings - run only when user is logged in and select the same user as interactive one; do not check "do not store password..."; do not check 'hidden') //// 2) environment is loaded - should be if user is fully logged on before batch is launched (https://superuser.com/questions/781444) //// 3) `c:\filepath` is able to be started that way at all (depends on what it is - try running it as a task). //// 4) `start` is able to detect the process still running.

Comment: Why don't you just launch the program directly from taskscheduler? And when it comes taskscheduler issues, an [mcve] would include the task XML, which you can export from the taskscheduler UI, or see `SCHTASKS /Query  /?`.